# How could i send a html5 sqlite database from an iphone?

Tags: sqlite, html

i'm developing a webapp for iphone/ipod and using the client's side database. I want my webapp to work mainly offline and allow users to fill the database and at a certain point i'd like to send my database to a server to process and store all the informations.
The problem is i can't find a proper way to send my tables to a server in order to fill its database with the one sent from the iphone. 
Does anyone has a clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest POSTing JSON to your server. 
So you would read the data from the client side database into JSON object form then take this and POST it to your server then let the server manage mapping into your datastore.